# How to convert .py and .ui (pyqt5 gui) file into .exe

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm using PyQt5 GUI (.ui file) separately and using these with my .py file the program is using pandas taking input from GUI line edit doing some search in excel(pandas data frame) and then displaying output at GUI Qtableview. (cdpt.ui, cdptsearchtoll.py, cdpt.xlsx chromedriver and pyicon.ico are in folder)
my pandas is using read_html as well.
Now I want to make a .exe file using pyinstaller I 'm doing but getting error "failed to execute script" 
I'm new to pyinstaller and unable to identify where the issue is? other than that my code is working fine. as expected!
please see below

```
C:\Users\AB43399\Desktop\cdpt_search_tool>pyinstaller -w -F -i 
"C:\Users\AB43399\Desktop\cdpt_search_tool\pyicon.ico" cdptsearchtool.py
1220 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
1220 INFO: Python: 3.7.1
1221 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
1231 INFO: wrote C:\Users\AB43399\Desktop\cdpt_search_tool\cdptsearchtool.spec
1238 INFO: UPX is not available.
1247 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\AB43399\\Desktop\\cdpt_search_tool',
'C:\\Users\\AB43399\\Desktop\\cdpt_search_tool']
1247 INFO: checking Analysis
1251 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
1252 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1273 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
1350 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
10235 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
10317 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
required by c:\users\ab43399\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe
12527 INFO: Caching module hooks...
12717 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\AB43399\Desktop\cdpt_search_tool\cdptsearchtool.py
13790 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt5.uic.port_v3
13970 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt5.uic.port_v2
14984 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
15954 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
23920 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
23964 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 
'c:\\users\\ab43399\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site- 
packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
26263 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
70917 INFO: Loading module hooks...
70917 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
71040 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
71585 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-jinja2.py"...
71673 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
72000 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lxml.etree.py"...
72003 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
74268 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.py"...
74308 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-openpyxl.py"...
74594 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pandas.py"...
84003 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.Image.py"...
86446 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.py"...
86479 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
86481 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module PIL.ImageQt
86482 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
86485 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module PIL.ImageQt
86485 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module PIL.ImageQt
86486 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
86488 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
86489 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
86493 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module PIL.ImageQt
86494 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
86494 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py"...
86499 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
86500 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
86502 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
88979 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
89480 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pycparser.py"...
89493 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
89507 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
91328 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
91334 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
91824 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
92457 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
93499 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.uic.py"...
93571 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytest.py"...
102252 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pythoncom.py"...
104849 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytz.py"...
105540 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
108030 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
111619 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...
112534 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
112605 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-win32com.py"...
114057 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
114058 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
114076 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
114078 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
116028 INFO: checking Tree
116033 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
116033 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
116557 INFO: checking Tree
116558 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
116558 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
116796 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
116930 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
116943 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
116999 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
117006 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
117013 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt5.py'
117060 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
122552 INFO: Looking for eggs
122552 INFO: Using Python library 
c:\users\ab43399\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python37.dll
122554 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
122614 INFO: Warnings written to 
C:\Users\AB43399\Desktop\cdpt_search_tool\build\cdptsearchtool\warn-cdptsearchtool.txt
122960 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to 
C:\Users\AB43399\Desktop\cdpt_search_tool\build\cdptsearchtool\xref-cdptsearchtool.html
123141 INFO: checking PYZ
123141 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
123142 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) 
C:\Users\AB43399\Desktop\cdpt_search_tool\build\cdptsearchtool\PYZ-00.pyz
126145 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) 
C:\Users\AB43399\Desktop\cdpt_search_tool\build\cdptsearchtool\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
126227 INFO: checking PKG
126227 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
126228 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
129181 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
129181 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
'C:\\users\\ab43399\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site- 
 packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
 129184 WARNING: was placed previously at
 129184 WARNING: ('PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
'C:\\users\\ab43399\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site- 
packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
'BINARY')
157741 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
157789 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\ab43399\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
157789 INFO: checking EXE
157790 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
157790 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
157897 INFO: SRCPATH [('C:\\Users\\AB43399\\Desktop\\cdpt_search_tool\\pyicon.ico', None)]
157897 INFO: Updating icons from ['C:\\Users\\AB43399\\Desktop\\cdpt_search_tool\\pyicon.ico'] to 
C:\Windows\Temp\tmplqtaq2qp
157915 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 132 bytes
157915 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 5355 bytes
157916 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 67624 bytes
157917 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 38056 bytes
157917 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 21640 bytes
157919 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 16936 bytes
157919 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 9640 bytes
157919 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 4264 bytes
157920 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 8 resource with 2440 bytes
157920 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 9 resource with 1128 bytes
157933 INFO: Appending archive to EXE 
C:\Users\AB43399\Desktop\cdpt_search_tool\dist\cdptsearchtool.exe
158455 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

I have seen warning one or two places 
like

```
91328 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
129181 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
```

but I don't understand what is missing and how to fix them are they the one who is causing the problem???

Any help/direction is really appreciated!

Comment: basically I'm getting an Importerror  unable to find Qt5Core.ll on path

Comment: Find that dll where pyqt is installed and copy it to the side of your executable

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you for your reply! I will try that as well


for now I found the solution I downgrade the PyQt5 from 5.13.1 to 5.12.1 and it works fine..!